tcbtheorem incorrectly displaying counter value
I'm writing a project in LaTeX, and I want to use tcolorbox theorems for my theorem typesetting and wish for the theorems to be numbered within the section (i.e. Theorem 1.2). Look at the following minimal working example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,}

\newcounter{thmcounter}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter=thmcounter]{THMbox}{Theorem}{}{thm}
\counterwithin{thmcounter}{section}

\begin{document}
\section{foo}
The theorem counter is currently \thethmcounter, but as soon as we use the \texttt{tcbtheorem} environment...
\begin{THMbox}{}{} ... the theorem counter displays differently \end{THMbox}
This updates the theorem counter and stores it correctly (it has updated to\thethmcounter), but it does not display it correctly in the theorem name.

\end{document}

This outputs the following:

Can anyone explain why this is happening and/or how to prevent it? I'm using Overleaf pdfLaTeX, if that's of any use.
Edit: I should also add that the reason I have created a counter instead of numbering within section is so I can then have corollaries number within that counter, i.e. Theorem 2.7 followed by Corollary 2.7.1.

welcome! counters always take (simply) integers. so the counter is never 1.0 or 1.1. but \thethmcounter doesn't print the counter itself but a formatted representation which may include the values of other counters e.g. the section number. so you need to modify the format of the counter in the title of the theorem using, most probably, the config options provided by the tcolorbox package.

Counters can only take integer values. LaTeX counters are just TeX counts under the hood. So the value of a counter can never be 1.1 or 1.0. \the<counter> doesn't print <counter> per se, however. It prints a representation of <counter> which could be (but usually isn't) entirely independent of <counter>.
To make this work with tcolorbox, you need to use the configuration methods the package provides. So it is no use telling LaTeX to number your theorems within sections. That only tells LaTeX when to reset the counter etc. It has nothing to do with what tcolorbox does with that counter.
Instead, just tell tcolorbox to label the theorems within sections and let the package argue it out with LaTeX if so inclined.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,}

\newcounter{thmcounter}
\newtcbtheorem[use counter=thmcounter,number within=section]{THMbox}{Theorem}{}{thm}

\begin{document}
\section{foo}
% Note that this theorem has been disproved and struck from the record.
The theorem counter is currently \thethmcounter, but as soon as we use the \texttt{tcbtheorem} environment...
\begin{THMbox}{}{} ... the theorem counter displays in just the same way.
\end{THMbox}
This updates the theorem counter and stores it correctly (it has updated to\thethmcounter), but it does not display it correctly in the theorem name.
\end{document}

